# Powersell delete subfolders where name not in sql output

Tags: powershell, admin

Trying to delete sub folders where the name is not part of a SQL output. Tried the below but -exclude doesnt seem to exclude any thing. Am I missing something obvious?

```
$SQL = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT id FROM files" -Database dbname -ServerInstance .\SQLEXPRESS
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\files -Exclude $SQL | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Setup:

PS> get-childitem -path G:\Test\TestDelete\Music -recurse -directory


    Directory: G:\Test\TestDelete\Music


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                             
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                             
d-----        8/26/2020   7:58 PM                Bread                                                                            
d-----        8/26/2020   7:58 PM                Buddy Holly                                                                      
d-----        8/26/2020   7:58 PM                Cat Stevens                                                                      

PS> $sql = "Bread","Cat Stevens"

#If your sql does not return an array it won't work!

PS> $sql -is [Array]
True

#Test of Command:

PS> get-childitem -path G:\Test\TestDelete\Music -recurse -directory -exclude $sql | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

#Verification of results:

PS> get-childitem -path G:\Test\TestDelete\Music -recurse -directory


    Directory: G:\Test\TestDelete\Music


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                             
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                             
d-----        8/26/2020   8:01 PM                Bread                                                                            
d-----        8/26/2020   8:01 PM                Cat Stevens
```

Note: Make sure your Path includes the last directory you DO NOT want deleted!

HTH